# Geoserver Docker image GDAL library extension error

Tags: gdal, geoserver

I have been trying to implement Geoserver with extension of gdal. To do this, I used official docker image of Geoserver

I used the command as follows in order to fetch image and associated extensions.

```
sudo docker run -it -p8080:8080 --env SKIP_DEMO_DATA=true --env INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=true --env STABLE_EXTENSIONS="app-schema,authkey,cas,control-flow,css,csw,dxf,excel,gdal,geofence,geopkg-output,grib,gwc-s3,mapml,wps,xslt,ysld,dfx,excel,imagemap,importer,libjpeg-turbo" --env COMMUNITY_EXTENSIONS="ogcapi-features,ogcapi-images,ogcapi-maps,ogcapi-styles,ogcapi-tiles" docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.24.x
```

But unfortunately I received error within the image as follows. What should I do in order to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in Advance,

[JNI GDAL Wrapper Version: unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccTab.png)

I tried to connect associated container via

```
docker exec -it cont_id bash
```

command and tried to change environment variables but I couldn't find the jni wrapper. Also I tried to implement some solutions I found in stackoverflow but They didn't work.

Comment: did you find any indication that the official image supports the gdal extension?